# How do Countdown can be repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, countdown

Try to open jsfiddle.net/3hjLb/1/ then click on "Try it" wait until the 0 and click "Try it" and see happen,

How do the "0" it could go back to 10 if you click on "Try it" a second time?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3hjLb/4/. Reset when counter becomes 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reset your counter variable to 10 before call onclick function

like this

```
<button onclick="javascript:counter=10; countDown()">Try it</button>
```

See [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3hjLb/6/)

Comment: thanks for the help of friends, this is very helpful :D

Answer (score 1):

try to set counter value in onclick event : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3hjLb/2/)**

```
<button onclick="counter = 10;countDown()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: yes this is also 3 correct answers, thank you very much friends :D

Answer (score 0):

using "if" condition is one option:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title> Bla! </title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var counter = 10;
            function CountDown(obj) {
                if (--counter < 0) counter = 10;
                obj.innerHTML = "counter=" + counter;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick='CountDown(this)'> Click to countdown (10) </button>
    </body>
</html>
```